# How about Artificial Post Reviewer that finds potential problems in the posts and suggests fixes before users posts?

Tags: feature-request

Why wasn't a thing like this implemented? We could forget about code with no fixed-font, about no 'i's that deserve to be capital and etc. It will lead new users to understand our standard format. While it can vary, but there are things that anyone would agree.

This tool could improve the quality here faster by giving new users jump and it will decrease post bans, and therefore decrease the 'harsh' stigma about Stack Overflow.

My opinion is that it will be worthwhile the cost to implement it.

Comment: _"Is this thing too expensive to implement?"_ I'm afraid yes. Human moderation is certainly better, and there are already some mechanisms to hint a user about bad points. If users ask bad questions, they'll get downvoted and closed, that's enough IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is better but costs time, this tool can improve the quality here faster by giving new users jump and it will give them less question\answer bans. I prefer to hear whatever it's too expensive from moderator.

Comment: what we need is to [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/165773)

Comment: There already is a bunch of quality filters that prevent bad posts from getting posted.

Comment: @Flexo Can I see the list maybe?

Comment: @KugBuBu I doubt such filters will be publicly available, if they were then people could perhaps learn to circumvent them. (I could be wrong, however, if they leave no room for manipulation -ie  more water tight than a mermaid’s brassiere, etc)

Comment: @James Oops, I thought that it was like the red thing, for example when you post just code then it will show message that it isn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

We do have the community user, who does some auto tasks:
[Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

> My opinion is that it will be worthwhile the cost to implement it.

Cost is not the issue. Stack has budgets, and some fantastic developers, but the issue is it's probably impossible.

When user written code (PHP etc) is involved it becomes impossible to cater for so many potentials.
For example, to know when `i` needs to be upper case or not, scripts would have to understand context, and this is unreachable where code is concerned as there are too many potential scenarios to cater for.

Example - a user writes:

> I want to check user login
>   My code defines the variable named i ($i) and I want i to be incremented by u (the variable $u I mean)

Does the scripts  you propose change any case for any of those *I*'s in the above quote? Does it make "*u*" to "*you*" - it cannot distinguish unless it knows context.

---

This could work on non-code Stack sites, so perhaps suggest it on MSE for non-code sites (check it hasn't already, as I'm sure it will have been suggested).

### Edit - in response to your comment

You cannot suggest potential changes to a user unless the suggested changes are in fact an improvement.
However, without more thought and detail in your proposal, currently your "artificial post reviewer" will return a *lot* of false positives and rubbish.
It's not acceptable for users to rake through such nonsense and silly suggestions.

What is the point in just swapping one issue for another?
Especially as some users will just *accept* the suggestions believing that if Stack suggested them then they must surely be ok.

Anyone who would take the time to review the proposed suggestions would likely be making their question clean anyway, and already doing whatever decent suggestions your system made.
You'd just be annoying them with silly and pointless suggestions.

Everyone else would just ignore it.

---

As it is, your proposal is asking to introduce a problematic system, suggest poor edits to a users question, and as a result would bring issues to the site. Stack wouldn't do such a thing.

"Take a look at these suggestions, some may be rubbish, ignore those, anything you feel is a good suggestion please change".

If you can make your proposal show such a system could suggest changes which would be useful and 100% correct, then perhaps it would be considered.

Comment: Because of that I said `potential` I didn't said anything about super-intelligence that can do NLP understand meaning and etc. Minimal check and then suggests.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "potential" then? Your question title is "*potential problems*". I didn't say you  proposed "super-intelligence", I just answered based on your proposal, which suggested "*We could forget about code with no fixed-font, about no 'i's that deserve to be capital*". I gave a reason your proposal doesn't work. If you want to re-address your proposal and change it, feel free, and I'll change my answer, or remove it, accordingly. Or if you can explain a bit more what you mean.

Comment: Potential, it means that it can be or but sometimes is not, when in the tool `word == "i"` goes true, it will suggest to capitalize it. If the user thinks this suggestion is improper then it won't apply the suggestion. This is what potential means, it can be something, the user will be the one to judge whatever it's useful and will permit the changes.

Comment: @KugBuBu see my answer edit :) I'm not saying *something* like what you propose isn't possible, I'm just saying your current proposal isn't ideal and needs some thought and additional structure. So it actually benefits Stack and it's users, rather than introduces issues and a bad system.

Comment: StackOverflow is self-government site, I think we can just make it opensource here, and anyone will edit it out and they will vote the edits and then accept. It will improve by time without much of cost.

Comment: @KugBuBu Stack wont (and shouldn't) introduce a system that would suggests bad edits. If you feel you know how this would work to our advantage, and would work well, then please improve your proposal to explain as such.

Comment: I meant that it will put opensource code that anyone will be able to edit it to make it better. Everytime there's issue users will try to fix it and other users will vote, then the system will change the code to it.

Comment: Don't we already have such a system with the question edit option? Again, make your proposal more clear - how it will work, what the benefits are, how to overcome some pitfalls, etc.

Comment: Issues with the system that suggests fixes I meant. I think I will pass on explaining, as you see my expression skills are bad. It would be better to make my own StackOverflow site ^^.

Comment: Your English is fine, certainly good enough to put forward your proposal. You just need to spend a bit more time thinking about the pros and cons, and spend time writing a decent proposal. Although, good luck with the other site ;)

Comment: The site thing was a joke. This is my expression skills, or just that it's just text without face expressions, thanks anyway. (WHY?) You gave me courage a bit, I think I will try but I am starting to think that it's worthless than I thought it was. Because we will have to treat issues a lot while it's just for new users. Meh.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your impression skills, I presumed it was a joke. My face showed sarcasm as I replied ;)